# do I have to check login session when initiating PHP class?

Tags: php, oop, session

I used to program php in procedural way. Since I would like to learn more about OOP I have decided to program php in OOP way for my new project.

Anyways, let's say I have a project that requires user to login. Which means in login.php once user enters the correct username and password, it will be redirected to index.php and will start loading all the products from the product table and display them nicely in index.php.

Before, how I did this was, in login.php I'll have the following code:

**login.php**

```
session_start();
...
if (loggedCorrect($user, $password)) {
     $_SESSION['loggedinuser'] = $user;
     //redirect to index.php
}
```

**index.php**

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedinuser']) {
      //select fields from products table and display them
      ...
}
```

so in OOP it will be something like:

**login.php**

```
session_start();
$user = new User($user, $password);
if ($user->hasCorrectLogin()) {
     $_SESSION['loggedinuser'] = $user->getUsername();
     //redirect to index.php
}
```

**index.php**

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedinuser']) {
     $products = new Products();
     //display all products
}
```

**Product class**

```
class Products {
    private $productArray;
    ...
    __construct() {
         //select all products from mySQL table then put every product in productArray
    }
...
}
```

My question are:

1. when initiating object (like Products in my case). do I have to check login session? if so, should I do it inside __contruct? or should I do it before the "class Products" line?
2. I also have a cronjob.php, which will be executed every x minutes. When it's executing, it will create some objects like Products and analysis them. So if login session checking is required, then I'm not sure how to make this works, as cronjob doesn't support session.

Please advise

Comment: How are you calling `loggedCorrect`? I notice you have `if ($user->hasCorrectLogin()) {` are they related?

Comment: In Object Oriented Programming you should be aware of the principle called Separation of Concerns. 

Why should a class model for Products care whether the user is logged in?? 

Your application should handle checking for a logged in session as you already have, and then display products.

Comment: @Fred-ii- loggedCorrect is a function and it's functionality is the same as $user-> hasCorrectLogin(). It's just one is the procedural way and the other one is OOP.

Comment: @Rottingham so what you saying is, as long as I have checked login session in index.php, I don't have to take care of it again in any classes that I have, am I correct?

Comment: Looks good to me the way you're doing it.  Let the page handle the session, objects should only be concerned about themselves not the application as a whole.  You want to be able to reuse an object in another application, if you put in application specific session vars into that object then it becomes tightly tied with that first application and may not work in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answers**

1. No. Your domain objects themselves should not be dependent on a logged in session; however, they may need a `User` instance to perform certain duties, such as only showing the products that a particular user is able to see.
2. Because of #1, this is now trivial.

**Code review**

First let's consider your login page code:

```
$user = new User($user, $password);
if ($user->hasCorrectLogin()) {
```

In this code, it would seem that User interacts with the database and has knowledge how to validate credentials. That seems a bit too much responsibility for a single class.

It could perform password validation by keeping the hashed password inside the object, but you would only need to validate a password once, so there's really no need to keep that field around. Another reason not to have it done here is when you need to consider strengthening your passwords on-the-fly, which could be a site policy to scale with growing hardware (e.g. when you're using bcrypt).

It should definitely not be doing database interaction; to separate both database interaction and password verification from the User class you could consider adding an authentication service.

```
try {
    $user = $authService->login($userName, $password);
    $_SESSION['loggedinuser'] = $user;
    // redirect to index.php
} catch (InvalidLoginException $e) {
    // oops, username or password invalid
}
```

Inside the authentication service, you could add another layer of abstraction to load the user record (using a data mapper for instance).

Instead of only storing the username in the session, you can store the whole User object as well. In some cases this may lead to inconsistencies, but it saves round trips to the database.

Now, let's observe the product overview page:

```
$products = new Products();
```

In terms of naming I would say that `Products` is not a good candidate to describe a collection of objects. A name such as `ProductList` or `ProductCollection` is better.

As with the authentication above, it's unclear how the `Products` class gets populated; it should come from some storage, so let's introduce the repository that will provide the list of products:

```
$productRepository = new ProductRepository($db);
$products = $productRepository->getAll();
```

In the simplest scenario, the repository gets initialized with a database instance; more levels of abstraction can be applied when necessary.